# How to refer to an Excel NamedRange in Visual Studio using Microsoft.Office.Interop

Tags: vb.net, excel, excel-interop, excel-dna, named-ranges

I'm transitioning from VBA to VB.NET for an Excel Add-in using ExcelDNA. Within my code, I'm trying to refer to a NamedRange by it's name (like I could in VBA) to set that Name's 'ReferTo' property. However, I get an error that it cannot convert the name I supplied to an Integer.  Error: Conversion from string "MyNamedRangeName" to type 'Integer' is not valid.

In the code below, you can see where the error occurs and why.

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Imports ExcelDna.Integration
Public Class Class1
    Sub SetReferToProperty()
        Dim ap As Excel.Application = ExcelDnaUtil.Application
        Dim wb as Excel.Workbook = ap.ActiveWorkbook

        'This is where the error occurs. Apparently, I can't (?) refer to    
        'the NamedRange by it's name. I need to use it's index.
        wb.Names("MyNamedRangeName").RefersTo = 0

        'If I use the Index instead (assume it's 1) it will work, but I
        'want to use the name instead - not the index.
        wb.Names(1).RefersTo = 0
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes (I'm not sure when exactly) VB.NET requires you to specify the collection property (in this case, `Items`) explicitly, and the default indexer doesn't work. So you need to say:

```
 wb.Names.Item("MyNamedRangeName").RefersTo = 0
```

Note that if you want to add a new name, you'd say:

```
wb.Names.Add("MyNamedRangeName", 0)
```

Comment: Wow Govert you are everywhere! =) That fixed it. Thanks for your help.